# Android Canvas.drawLine not smooth, not consistent

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-view

I am trying to use `Canvas.drawLine` method to draw a polygon

Here's the code that I am using

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(cache);
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setStrokeWidth(16);
paint.setColor(this.currentDrawing.getColor());
paint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
systemCanvas.drawBitmap(cache, 0, 0, paint);
paint.setStrokeCap(Cap.ROOUND);
canvas.drawLine(from.getLeft(), from.getTop(), to.getLeft(), to.getTop(), paint);
```

And this is the output that I am getting:

[image]

Notice the way the lines render, they break on the round shapes and don't join smoothly.  I understand why is it happening but I don't know how to make it smooth and consistent.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check this answer out because it is similar to your question:

[Android How to draw a smooth line following your finger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287949/android-how-to-draw-a-smooth-line-following-your-finger)

Please let me know if this helps!

Comment: thanks.. I worked out on path already after raising the question.  This is a kind of weird thing.  But whenever I fall into a problem, I research well and post on SO, after which most of the time I solve it myself.

Giving you a +1 and correct answer anyways :)  .. Thanks

Comment: Thanks alot! Just curious, what kind of app are you creating? I've thought about doing something with gestures/using the draw/paint library myself :)

Answer (score 8):

You may also want to do this

mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);

Comment: this improves the drawing after I draw the lines using samples of the data (co-ordinates), but this alone wouldn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to activate hardware acceleration. If you don't activate this, you can not use method of antialias, cap, join and etc.

Comment: fine but this will not resolve the issue since I needed to do sampling of co-ordinates and join them instead of drawing a pixel on each sample