# How can I determine which square in my memory game was pressed?

Tags: java, android, algorithm

I want to develop an simple memory game on Android.

The memory game have squares like the picture below. How should I determine which of the square is pressed? Should I use image buttons? Personally I don't think it is an good idea to make the game with image buttons. Could you suggest me an solution on how I should determine which of the square is pressed?

[image]

Comment: I'd make each square is a Button or an ImageView or a TextView or ... How else woud you do, if not?

Comment: I want to use the Graphics class to draw the image on the screen. What I know is where on the screen an image is placed and where the user clicks.

Comment: create a table with each square a cell. Render the cell using renderer and add listener to the table which will give you the row and column in the table...

Answer (score 1):

I think `ImageView`s for each square is the best way to go, no need for buttons.

Note: `View`s would be sufficient, you can implement `onClick(View)` for any view.

**UPDATE:**
Since you have a Graphics (as opposed to `View`s) for your squares, you may indeed use the coordinates to determine which square is touched, but I don't think this is the easiest, nor the best approach.

Why don't you want a `GridLayout` or a `TableLayout` containing `ImageView`s?

Comment: Because I want to use animation also when a certain square is pressed, Is it possible to have animation in gridview? 
I want to make a game with good graphics, I am not sure if gridview is a good solution.

Comment: I've never used it myself, but you can take a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/GridLayoutAnimationController.html

Comment: Is it better to use Views or GridView to make the game work on all screen sizes?

Comment: I guess yes, cleaner and easier to implement than using Graphics explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a view where you draw the squares then put a onClick() listener in that view and inside the onClick() do like this: (this is taken from a Sudoku game I made)

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
{
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // keep where the user first touch the screen
            touchedX = (int) event.getX() / wid33; // the square width
            touchedY = (int) event.getY() / hei33; // the square height
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            // see if the touched square is the same
            int X = (int) event.getX() / wid33;
            int Y = (int) event.getY() / hei33;
            if (X == touchedX && Y == touchedY)
            {
             // the square is the same, do what you have to do
            }
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            touchedX = -1;
            touchedY = -1;
            break;

        default:
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) or even OpenGL ES to render your game. This approach gives you more flexibility and better performance.

To check witch square was touched handle touch event you can use [OnTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11796538/3519587) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16650419/draw-in-canvas-by-finger-android) answer might be helpful to start your code.