# Android: Glow touched area

Tags: android

I am looking to glow an area around the touch point, pro grammatically. I am well aware that there is an option of setting it in the settings(Developers Option->Show Touch). Quick help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you be more specific? What would be the area to highlight?

Comment: the area around the touched point. Say for example, 2 cm circular area around the touched point, within the app which, i am developing.

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at the Android Fingerpaint example

You can download the "SDK Samples" in the SDK Manager in Eclipse. Then you can find the example at:

`<sdk>\samples\android-<version>\ApiDemos\src\com\example\android\apis\graphics`

Then try looking up examples of drawing a circle on the screen. 
Here is one:
[Draw Circle on touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11796357/draw-circle-on-touch)