# How to get a Context from an ImageView

Tags: java, android, touch

I am trying to make an ImageView be a surface that I can draw on with my finger.

I have followed [Android 2D Graphics Example](http://marakana.com/s/android_2d_graphics_example,1036/index.html), which resulted in making a whole screen drawable (with some issues, discussed in question [8287949](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287949/android-how-to-draw-a-smooth-line-following-your-finger), but somewhat disconnected from what I am trying to do.)

I am working with:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceStatA);
    // getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    // requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    drawView = new DrawView(this);
    drawView.requestFocus();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

I'm thinking I need to change `drawView = new DrawView(this)` to something that would reference the Context of the resource I define in `activity_main.xml`:

```
ImageView
    android:id="@+id/canvasview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnRed"
    android:background="@drawable/kitty"
```

However, I either don't know what I'm looking for in the API reference, or I'm not finding it.

The class for DrawView is documented at [Android 2D Graphics Example](http://marakana.com/s/android_2d_graphics_example,1036/index.html), so I won't repeat it here.

I have been working through AppInventor, and trying to duplicate what I learn there in Eclipse using the real Android SDK, but I'm feeling stumped on Tutorial #1, so sorry for the newbie question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Context` used to create the `View` is actually the `Activity` so it's already assigned to the `this` reference.  It's set when you call `setContentView()`.

Also, [View#getContext()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getContext%28%29).

So to retrieve the `Context` you would to get a reference to the View then call `getContext()`.  In this specific case, it would be

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.canvasview);
Context c = img.getContext();
```

Comment: Ah, thanks.  It looks like `Context c = img.getContext();` was throwing a NullPointerException, which was solved by putting `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` above the call to `getContext`.  The DrawView class is getting instantiated, but now the onTouchHandler event isn't getting fired, so I'm looking at that.  Thanks for the help!