# Touch move Android not smooth

Tags: android, draw, touchmove

I used this code:
In onCreate:

```
imageView.setOnTouchListener((OnTouchListener) this);
```

And onTouch:

```
 case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                canvas.drawLine(oldX, oldY, event.getX(), event.getY(), paint);
                imageView.invalidate();
```

If layout only contain one imageView, draw very smooth. But I add 2 3 or more than the view (button, image background), action_Move get event slowly and draw not smooth. Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

please refer to [how to have smooth and quick drawing in a fingerPaing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13631149/how-to-have-smooth-and-quick-drawing-in-a-fingerpaing)
or use draw circle to fill the begin and end, also file the gap betwee two lines

Answer (score 0):

Use `getRawX()` and `getRawY()` instead of `getX()` and `getY()`