# Android google maps - make polyline more straighter /smoother

Tags: android, location, android-maps, polyline

I am creating app to draw my walking path by GPS. Everything is okay, path is drawing when I walk, but I have one question - it is possible somehow to make path line straighter programmatically?

For example. First, after walking I see my path like this(it is not polyline, it is polygon in example, but I think you will get the idea):
https://www.dropbox.com/s/763mq0wja6x7lpy/11.png

But after saving, app made path more straighter/smoother:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/npwkz9coqve7m4g/22.png

How to do this? Because I don't have any idea.

I am drawing path with `LocationListener`:

> LocationManager locationManager =
>   (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
>
> ```
>     Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
>   //criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW); 
>     criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
>     criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
>     criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
>     criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
>     criteria.setSpeedRequired(false);       
>     String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
>     locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 500, 3, this );
> ```

And onLocationChanged listener:

> @Override
>   public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
>
> ```
>           if(lastLocationloc == null) 
>                           lastLocationloc = location;     
>           LatLng lastLatLng= locationToLatLng(lastLocationloc);
>           LatLng thisLatLng= locationToLatLng(location);
>           mMap.addPolyline
>                        (new PolylineOptions().add(lastLatLng).add(thisLatLng).width(4).color(Color.RED));
>           lastLocationloc = location;             
>   }
> ```

Comment: Not sure but i'd guess its just because of your `lastLatLng` and `thisLatLng`. Lat and long info is always a little shaky, so if you use this as straight input to drawing a line...the line will be shaky. You could try to adjust your latlong info a little to decrease noise, but this might be tricky.

Comment: What do you mean by saying "adjust your latlong" ?

Answer (score 2):

The LocationManager will never give you exact locations. Therefore, while you may not be walking in a non-smooth way, the GPS coordinates you get will always be jumpy, even if you set a very high accuracy in your Criteria.

So, when you draw the path, you may consider using [Android's Path API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html)

For some code on this, look at this answer:

[Android How to draw a smooth line following your finger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287949/android-how-to-draw-a-smooth-line-following-your-finger/8289516#8289516)

Comment: And where I find quadTo function for maps? Because I think this is that I was looking for. Or somehow to use path function for map?

Comment: This goes a bit further than this space is able to contain. In short: You need to create your own Overlay and add it to the map. In the Overlay, you override the draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mv, ...) method. The canvas is important, as you can now draw directly on the map. To convert the locations to the respective pixels on the map, you will have to get the projection and convert to pixels like so: `mapView.getProjection().toPixels(...)`. at this point you will now have to apply the Path.quadTo() method to draw the smooth path.

Comment: Okey, i got idea, but i think it won't work correctly. Because you can be walking and at the same time dragging map(or the map camera can be following your movement), so i think your method can draw line to wrong pixels. But by the way, looking at your given links I accidentally found this link http://johan.karlsteen.com/2011/07/30/improving-google-maps-polygons-with-b-splines/ , and it's the best solution I found so far. Thanks for Your help!

Comment: nice link. regarding wrong pixels: that will not happen. draw is called with each update on an empty canvas. So you can zoom, pan, whatever... as long as you get the current projection and use that to convert lat/long coordinates to pixels, you will get the correct result.