# Draw a line with curved edges in Android

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I am using `canvas.drawLine`  to draw some line in android but the lines are too sharp but i need a curved edges
[image]

Here the 1 is what i have and 2  is what i want to achieve, means a line with curved edges rather than straight edges

How can I achieve that ??

**EDIT 2:**

I am trying to use the Canvas object to to draw a line. but the lines have a sharp edge, I need a rounded off edge
I am using the Paint object

```
mPaint = new Paint();
mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK)
```

Any help would be appreciated great.

Comment: Paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND)

Comment: @GareginSargsyan : Can you post it as answer so that i can accept it

Comment: Your question is put on hold. I cannot post an answer. You should improve it, or remove it. You should read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287949/android-how-to-draw-a-smooth-line-following-your-finger

Comment: @GareginSargsyan : Now you can post your answer. It seems flagging the moderators hold and comment has removed  (also my comments too), they felt touchy perhaps ;)

Comment: Finally the justice has been served :)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use the `Paint.setStrokeCap()` method. You need `Paint.Cap.ROUND`. The default one is `Paint.Cap.BUTT`. There is a similar `Path` property that is called path join. It determines how to draw the parts of the path where it's constituent segments join. To set it use `Path.setPathJoin()`. You might need it in the future.
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use below**

```
pitchPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND)
```

Comment: How is that different from the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

this is for **kotlin Jetpack Compose** users :
use the **cap** attribute

```
Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {

            // Fetching width and height for
            // setting start x and end y

            val canvasHeight = size.height
            
            // drawing a line between start(x,y) and end(x,y)
            drawLine(
                start = Offset(x = 0f, y = 0.12f * canvasHeight),
                end = Offset(x = 0f, y =0.5f *canvasHeight),
                color = Color.Red,
                strokeWidth = 10F,
                cap = StrokeCap.Round
            )
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
path = new Path();
path.moveTo(50, 50);
path.lineTo(50, 500);
path.lineTo(200, 500);
path.lineTo(200, 300);
path.lineTo(350, 300);

float radius = 50.0f;
CornerPathEffect cornerPathEffect = new CornerPathEffect(radius);
paint.setPathEffect(cornerPathEffect);
// this setPathEffect will set the curve edges for every new joining

canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
```

> Go through this link , [This Link will teach you proper usages](http://learing-android.blogspot.com/2014/05/draw-rounded-corner-line-along-path.html)