# How to draw pie like chart in Android

Tags: android, user-interface, custom-controls

How can I draw something like the circular chart in image below in android :

[image]

Comment: It seems a grey circle and colored 3 arcs... All of them sharing the same center point and the same radius.

Comment: @DerGolem how to round end points of arc?

Comment: Like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/20823792/2649012

Comment: have you found any solution for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this libabry.. ? it has pie charts

https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart

Documentation is [here](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki)

Comment: It's heavy for my small project, I just need pie chart.

Comment: I don't think there is a easier way to do this other than using a library

Comment: @Aryan There is. Simply use `drawCircle()` and `drawArc()`.

Comment: @AVEbrahimi: Define heavy :-) The whole library comes in a 600kb jar file.

Comment: Using pie chart graph from MP Chart, how can I set the curve to the corner in android?

Comment: @PhilippJahoda need help can we design pie chart like this using your library

Comment: What about proguard etc. @PhilippJahoda Doesn't that remove unused references and classes

Comment: how to enable animation om curved part.??for default view animation is working fine but for curved animation is not working! @PhilippJahoda

Comment: @ParthBhayani use pieChart.setDrawRoundedSlices(true) from MP chart.

Answer (score 0):

try this library

You can draw one by one layers

https://github.com/RamiJ3mli/PercentageChartView