# How to send touch event equally to gesture Overlay view and Canvas

Tags: android, gesture, ontouchlistener, android-gesture

I do not know what is going on. I am hiding the gesture drawing , rather then this I am planning to show the the drawing drawn by the paint and canvas.I am using the drawing panel class which is working fine if used alone as shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287949/android-how-to-draw-a-smooth-line-following-your-finger) question. It is drawing perfectly.

Now what I was thinking and tried is this , I have implemented the gesture overlay view alone and it was working and detecting gesture. But due to some reasons I am manipulating these two methods all together 1.Paint to draw on canvas 2 gesture to recognize user gesture while drawing on Canvas

Now what I am trying and expecting is , When user draw A on  canvas the the canvas starting following the user finger and starts drawing but I think as when the gesture overlay starts detecting gesture, it looks like that the touch is passed to gesture overlay view where as the Paint and canvas stops further drawing.

**What I want :**

I want that the touch event should be received by the canvas and gesture overlay equally , so that they both work independently.

In simple Words , Do you have any idea how to send touch event to both of these equally ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok there it is , I found the solution , if some one also trying to get it , I mean to use Gesture overlay view , while having other  child. Just put the following line in the gesture overlay view xml

> **android:eventsInterceptionEnabled="false"**

and it would start working .