# Animate image along path on Android?

Tags: android, animation, path, imageview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android, move bitmap along a path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460508/android-move-bitmap-along-a-path)

Is there a way to animate an ImageView's position along a path on the Android as with a CGPath on the iPhone? I have scoured the web for a solution to this, but no one has even seemed to ask about it. I didn't see anything in the Android docs describing this functionality.

Comment: I know this is rather old, but for anyone else looking for help, take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849554/problem-to-achieve-curved-animation/8454990#8454990

Answer (score 4):

I created a subclass of Animation named PathAnimation, which can animate along a path.

You can just create a new PathAnimation with a Path, and use it like any other Animations.

https://github.com/coocood/PathAnimation

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to use an Animation resource. Here is a sample one that will slide view in from the left. You'd put something like this into an xml file in your projects res/anim folder.

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/overshoot_interpolator">

    <translate android:fromXDelta="100%p" android:toXDelta="0%p" android:duration="700"/>


</set>
```

Then to use it from the java code you are going to do something like this:

```
Animation slideLeftIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_left_in);
yourImageView.startAnimation(slideLeftIn);
```

This particular example is using the overshoot_interpolator which will make the view that its applied to go past its target and then bounce back. For more info about different interpolaters, and using Animation resources [check out the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html)

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, that is animation along a straight line. I would like to animate along a curved path.