# curve animation in android along y coordinate

Tags: android, android-listview, android-animation

To be precise i am working on dropping view to list and when user drops the view it is supposed to go in a curved path to the list in listview .

PS:I have seen lot of animations but along the x coordinate and not along the y coordinate . 
Appreciate all your help .

I have used the ArcTranslate class from 
[Problem to achieve curved animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849554/problem-to-achieve-curved-animation)
but that is for curve along the x cooordinate .

The code for arc animation :

```
    public class ArcAnimation extends Animation {

private Point start;
private Point end;
private Point middle;
private final float mFromXValue;
private final float mToXValue;
private final float mYValue;
private final int mFromXType;
private final int mToXType;
private final int mYType;

/**
 * A translation along an arc defined by three points and a Bezier Curve
 *
 * @param duration - the time in ms it will take for the translation to complete
 * @param fromXType - One of Animation.ABSOLUTE, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, or Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT.
 * @param fromXValue - Change in X coordinate to apply at the start of the animation
 * @param toXType - One of Animation.ABSOLUTE, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, or Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT.
 * @param toXValue - Change in X coordinate to apply at the end of the animation
 * @param yType - One of Animation.ABSOLUTE, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, or Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT.
 * @param yValue - Change in Y coordinate to apply at the middle of the animation (the radius of the arc)
 */
public ArcAnimation(long duration, int fromXType, float fromXValue,
        int toXType, float toXValue, int yType, float yValue){
    setDuration(duration);

     mFromXValue = fromXValue;
     mToXValue = toXValue;
     mYValue = yValue;

     mFromXType = fromXType;
     mToXType = toXType;
     mYType = yType;

}

/** Calculate the position on a quadratic bezier curve given three points
 *  and the percentage of time passed.
 * from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve
 * @param interpolatedTime - the fraction of the duration that has passed where 0<=time<=1
 * @param p0 - a single dimension of the starting point
 * @param p1 - a single dimension of the middle point
 * @param p2 - a single dimension of the ending point
 */
private long calcBezier(float interpolatedTime, float p0, float p1, float p2){
    return Math.round((Math.pow((1 - interpolatedTime), 2) * p0)
           + (2 * (1 - interpolatedTime) * interpolatedTime * p1)
           + (Math.pow(interpolatedTime, 2) * p2));
}

@Override
protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
    float dx = calcBezier(interpolatedTime, start.x, middle.x, end.x);
    float dy = calcBezier(interpolatedTime, start.y, middle.y, end.y);

    t.getMatrix().setTranslate(dy, dx);
}

@Override
public void initialize(int width, int height, int parentWidth, int parentHeight) {
    super.initialize(width, height, parentWidth, parentHeight);
    float startX = resolveSize(mFromXType, mFromXValue, height, parentHeight);
    float endX = resolveSize(mToXType, mToXValue, height, parentHeight);
    float middleY = resolveSize(mYType, mYValue, height, parentHeight);
    float middleX = startX + ((endX-startX)/2);
    start = new Point((int)startX, 0);
    end = new Point((int)endX, 0);
    middle = new Point((int)middleX, (int)middleY);
}
}
```

With the following code the object drops straight to the list but not in curve manner .How to get the arc animation working ?

Thanks !

Comment: What have you tried? Also for animations it might be nice if you link us to where we can see the animation you're striving for to ensure we're on the same page.

Comment: @Preethi did you achieve it?