# Android animate view along a curved path

Tags: android, animation, viewanimator

I'm trying to move my image from one point to another using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849554/problem-to-achieve-curved-animation/8454990#8454990) to achieve my animation. However this animation is not showing. Below is the code I'm using

```
ArcTranslate animation = new ArcTranslate(1000,Animation.ABSOLUTE,fromPos[0],toPos[0],Animation.ABSOLUTE,fromPos[1],toPos[1]);
animation.start();
```

I'm having another doubt too. How does this animation figures out which view to animate? Does it just takes the view in the given fromPos??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should attach the animation to a view. Usually, the following works well:

```
View.startAnimation(animation);
```

If you use this, remove the animation.start(). Alternatively you can first attach the animation, and start it later:

```
View.setAnimation(animation);
```

And then call animation.start() later.