# Creating Animation class problem

Tags: android, android-animation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problem to achieve curved animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849554/problem-to-achieve-curved-animation)

Can I create my own Animation class which will move my image in a curved path? If anybody have any idea or link to any post then please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a Frame by Frame animation. You can position the object step by step to create a curve. That will be of limited reuse, but you can do it.

Or you can write your own animation to create a subclass of TweenAnimation that can animate along a curve. If you're good with math and can understand bezier curves then that might be a straight forward option. Once you have that class you could easily animate across any curved path, but it's more work.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve

Here's some VB code:

http://www.codetoad.com/vb_bezier.asp

Here's some Java code:

http://www.math.ubc.ca/~cass/gfx/bezier.html

And also take a look at these questions

[animate-image-along-path-on-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5035669/animate-image-along-path-on-android)

Comment: Thanks hussain bhai.In your last link there is no solution for curved animation.And 3rd link is very very big and difficult to understand.I read it but i think it cannot be applied for android.