# Android move object along a path

Tags: android, animation, path, geometry

I have created a path and circle and displayed both of them on screen as follows:

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        
        Path sPath = new Path();
        sPath.moveTo(100, 100);
        sPath.lineTo(300, 100);
        sPath.lineTo(300, 300);
        sPath.lineTo(100,300);
        sPath.lineTo(100,100);
        sPath.close();
        
        Paint ballPaint = new Paint();
        ballPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        Paint pathPaint = new Paint();
        pathPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        
        canvas.drawPath(sPath, ballPaint);
        canvas.drawCircle(100,100,20,pathPaint);
    }
```

i would like to have the circle move along the path, how can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to move your circle a little bit each frame towards the next waypoint and detect once it gets there, then start moving toward the next.  There is no built in system that I know of.

Answer (score 18):

Here are the animators I use:

Purpose: Move View "view" along Path "path"

v21+:

```
ValueAnimator pathAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "x", "y", path)
```

v11+:

```
ValueAnimator pathAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0.0f, 1.0f);

pathAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
float[] point = new float[2];

@Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        float val = animation.getAnimatedFraction();
        PathMeasure pathMeasure = new PathMeasure(path, true);
        pathMeasure.getPosTan(pathMeasure.getLength() * val, point, null);
        view.setX(point[0]);
        view.setY(point[1]);
    }
});
```

Comment: How can I rotate my view after each contour. I have 4 points. I simply create path using lineto. Now I want to rotate my view on each of these 4 points. How can I do this?

Answer (score 17):

Yes, it's possible to move image along path. I will provide simple solution to show the principle. The following code will animate the circle along the path.

```
int iCurStep = 0;// current animation step

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    PathMeasure pm = new PathMeasure(sPath, false);
    float fSegmentLen = pm.getLength() / 20;//we'll get 20 points from path to animate the circle
    float afP[] = {0f, 0f};

    if (iCurStep <= 20) {
        pm.getPosTan(fSegmentLen * iCurStep, afP, null);
        canvas.drawCircle(afP[0],afP[1],20,pathPaint);
        iCurStep++;
        invalidate();
    } else {
        iCurStep = 0;
    };
};
```

Answer (score 7):

v21+: this creates a quadratic bezier curve on a path and animates myView along it.

```
final Path path = new Path();
path.quadTo(controlX, controlY, finalX, finalY);
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myView, View.X, View.Y, path).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do this is with `ContraintLayout` and then add a keyframe between the points on the path you want to animate, as described here: https://medium.com/google-developers/defining-motion-paths-in-motionlayout-6095b874d37.