# Moving along a Path by touching

Tags: android

I'm writting a game and I want the character walking along a path touched by finger.

For example, I draw a circle or a bezier curve, the character will walk by it then from start to the end.

By "FingerPaint" demo I already know how to get a smooth "Path" and daw it, while I don't know how to use "Path" to let the object moves by it.

I also tried to capture the touch points (x,y) in "ACTION_MOVE" statues of "onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)". While, those points are a series of points disconnected with each other, not as smooth as and as close as the "Path" drawed by finger.

Looking forwards to your suggestions about this. Thanks in advance. Yu Jin

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9048540/1013482) I showed how to move a circle along path. And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9027248/1013482) I move and rotate an image along path.  It's quite simple. I hope it will help you.