# Move object along path with finger

Tags: android, path, drag-and-drop, move, custom-draw

Following what is explained on [Android move object along a path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154370/android-move-object-along-a-path) I drawed a circle path and could animate an object along it

Now I need to move the same object along the same path but using the finger. Basically it should be like a drag and drop but using the path as a guide.

How can I do such a thing?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Nobody knows how to do so?

Answer (score 0):

U can try to get the pixel color of the touched point, then u can check if that color matches a pre-defined  path color. 
i had the same problem and find that very useful.