# Move an item over a path

Tags: android, android-studio, layout, path

In android studio i have this layout.

I want the **red ball** bellow the layout to be **move on the path** .

The **bath** is an **photo** which I put it in background.

I search a lot but I do not found a way to do that.

I need an example or keywords I can search for it.

This is layout image

[image: his is layout image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the experience to work with your plan but you can see the answers to the link below. 
I hope useful for you :)

check this out -> [Android move object along a path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154370/android-move-object-along-a-path)