# Animate ImageView along Path Android

Tags: android, path, android-animation

I searched all over Internet for this with no success. I need to Animate an ImageView along a Path. I have created a Path using:

```
Path path = new Path()    
path.moveTo(0, 0);
path.lineTo(184,776);
path.lineTo(184,780);
path.lineTo(184,790);
path.lineTo(184,810);
path.lineTo(230, 900);

ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
```

Is there any way I can move img along path?
Thank you all

Comment: I haven't tried this yet, but [this](https://github.com/coocood/PathAnimation) might help :)

Comment: Ive seen that, do you know how to use it with the ImageView?

Comment: No :( I didn't try it yet

Answer (score 2):

Here are the animators I use:

Purpose: Move View "view" along Path "path"

v21+:

```
ValueAnimator pathAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "x", "y", path)
```

v11+:

```
ValueAnimator pathAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0.0f, 1.0f);

pathAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
float[] point = new float[2];

@Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        float val = animation.getAnimatedFraction();
        PathMeasure pathMeasure = new PathMeasure(path, true);
        pathMeasure.getPosTan(pathMeasure.getLength() * val, point, null);
        view.setX(point[0]);
        view.setY(point[1]);
    }
});
```

Same as: [Android, move bitmap along a path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460508/android-move-bitmap-along-a-path/30254774#30254774)