# Android set bitmap as pathEffect for paint

Tags: android

I want to know is there any way in Android draw a custom curve line with the effect which i set. I want to set the bitmap path effect. Like in image below.

I want to get next result :

[image]

If this effect i can do with another way i want to know how i can do it.

Comment: i don't know if this will help you but i saw (cool) demo by romain guy on path finding: http://www.curious-creature.com/2013/12/21/android-recipe-4-path-tracing/

Answer (score 0):

I think [the example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460508/android-move-bitmap-along-a-path) will get you started (see the answer with the most votes, not the accepted answer). You can modify the path in the snippet such that it uses `quadTo` or cubicTo`  calls to draw a curve like in your picture, then step along it using the loop shown, drawing multiple bitmaps with, for each, random offsets for scale and distance from the path (using a separate set of matrices).